# Pandas: groupby then count based on condition gives NaN

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I have the following dataset:

```
+----+------+
| ID | Type |
+----+------+
| a  | New  |
+----+------+
| b  | Old  |
+----+------+
| b  | Old  |
+----+------+
| b  | New  |
+----+------+
| c  | Old  |
+----+------+
```

I'm trying to group by ID, and then count the number of `New` occurences for each group. So for example I would have `a=1`, `b=2`, and `c=0`.

Here's what I've tried:

```
df['NewAmount'] = df.groupby('ID')['Type'].apply(
    lambda x: x[x == 'New'].count())
```

And I get this:

```
+----+------+----------+
| ID | Type | NewAmount|
+----+------+----------+
| a  | New  | NaN      |
+----+------+----------+
| b  | Old  | NaN      |
+----+------+----------+
| b  | Old  | NaN      |
+----+------+----------+
| b  | New  | NaN      |
+----+------+----------+
| c  | Old  | NaN      |
+----+------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try with `transform`

```
df['out'] = df['Type'].eq('New').groupby(df['ID']).transform('sum')
```

Comment: Can you explain why you used `sum` and not `count` in the transform?

Comment: @mokiliiiLo Cause I an using the eq in the front , the item is New it will return True , after groupby we can just sum how many True it is , it will equal to do the count ~